# Why directly changing a migrate file does not change the schema file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My current migrate file is

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :movies, :force => true do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :rating
      t.text :description
      t.datetime :release_date
      # Add fields that let Rails automatically keep track
      # of when movies are added or modified:
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :movies
  end
end
```

I try to change release_date type to integer. So I directly change the file to

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :movies, :force => true do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :rating
      t.text :description
      t.integer :release_date
      # Add fields that let Rails automatically keep track
      # of when movies are added or modified:
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :movies
  end
end
```

Please pay attention, the release_date type has been changed. But after I run

> bundle exec rake db:migrate

It still produce the same schema file as before. I am so confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you've already run your migration. So before you want to change it, you should rollback it first:

```
bundle exec rake db:rollback
```

then you should modify it and run again:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I want!

Comment: Assuming it's the last one `bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo`  will rollback and re-migrate the last migration

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to dropping and upping the migration, you could make a new migration to change the column type.

```
class ChangeMoviesReleaseTypeToInteger < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :movies, :release_date, :integer
  end

  def down
    change_column :movies, :release_date, :datetime
  end
end
```

Just as a side note, `release_date` is a confusing name for an integer field - most people would expect it to be a datetime as you had originally.

Answer (score 0):

**down** will remove the table

> rake db:migrate:down VERSION=file_name(exclude extension)

**up** will create with new changes

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=file_name(exclude extension)
```